# error in downloading file with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to download some files from a free dataset using Beautifulsoup.
I repeat the same process for two similar links in the web page.

[This](http://umcd.humanconnectomeproject.org/umcd/default/update/640) is the page address.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

first_url = "http://umcd.humanconnectomeproject.org/umcd/default/download/upload_data.region_xyz_centers_file.bcf53cd53a90f374.55434c415f43434e5f41504f455f4454495f41504f452d335f355f726567696f6e5f78797a5f63656e746572732e747874.txt" 
second_url="http://umcd.humanconnectomeproject.org/umcd/default/download/upload_data.connectivity_matrix_file.bfcc4fb8da90e7eb.55434c415f43434e5f41504f455f4454495f41504f452d335f355f636f6e6e6563746d61742e747874.txt"
# labeled as Connectivity Matrix File in the webpage
def download_file(url, file_name):
    myfile = requests.get(url)
    open(file_name, 'wb').write(myfile.content)

download_file(first_url, "file1.txt")
download_file(second_url, "file2.txt")
```

**output files:**

```
file1.txt:
50.118248 53.451775 39.279296 
51.417612 67.443649 41.009074 
...
file2.txt
<html><body><h1>Internal error</h1>Ticket issued: <a href="/admin/default/ticket/umcd/89.41.15.124.2020-04-30.01-59-18.c02951d4-2e85-4934-b2c1-28bce003d562" target="_blank">umcd/89.41.15.124.2020-04-30.01-59-18.c02951d4-2e85-4934-b2c1-28bce003d562</a></body><!-- this is junk text else IE does not display the page: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx //--></html>
```

but I can download the second_url from the chrome browser properly (contains some numbers).
I tried to set user-agent

```
headers = {'User-Agent': "Chrome/6.0.472.63 Safari/534.3"}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

but did not work.

**Edit**
The site does not need login to get the data. I opened the page in a private mode browser then downloaded the file in second_url.
Direct coping the second_url in address bar gave error:

```
Internal error
Ticket issued: umcd/89.41.15.124.2020-04-30.03-18-34.49c8cb58-7202-4f05-9706-3309b581af76
```

Do you have any idea?
Thank you in advance for any guide.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a Python issue. The second URL gives the same error both in Curl and in my browser.

It's odd to me the second URL would be shorter by the way. Are you sure you copied it right?

Comment: I tried the url in private mode.  It get the same error. In normal mode of browser I can download the file. I need to set the cookies right?